# How does GMail implement Comet?

Tags: gmail, comet, httpwatch

With the help of HttpWatch, I tried to figure out how GMail implements Comet.

I login in to GMail with two accounts, one in IE and the other in Firefox. Chatting in GTalk in GMail with some magic words like "WASSUP". Then, I logoff both GMail accounts, filter any http content without "WASSUP" string. The result shows which HTTP request is the streaming channel. (Note: I have to logoff. Otherwise, never-ending HTTP would not show content in HttpWatch.)

The result is interesting. The URL for stream channel is like:

> https://mail/channel/bind?VER=8&at=xn3j33vcvk39lkfq.....

There is no surprise that GMail do Comet in IE with IFRAME. The Http content starts with "`<html><body>`".

Originally, I guessed that GMail does Comet in Firefox with multipart XmlHttpRequest. To my surprise, the response header doesn't have "multipart/x-mixed-replace" header. The response headers are as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Sat, 20 Mar 2010 01:52:39 GMT
X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: GSE
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

Unfortunately, the HttpWatch doesn't tell whether a HTTP request is from XmlHttpRequest or not. The content is not HTML but JSON. It looks like a response for XHR, but that would not work for Comet without multipart/x-mixed-replace, right?

Is there any way else to figure out how GMail implements Comet?

**Update:**
After further investigation, I believe GMail implements Comet this way:
1) in IE, it use a forever-hidden-iframe;
2) in Firefox, it use forever-XHR without multipart/x-mixed-replace header. The client will response in conditon (readyState == 3) OR (readyState == 4). That is, in both interactive state and complete state.

Answer (score 15):

Per [this article](http://www.ekhoury.com/blog/2007/02/07/ajax-alternatives-gmail-choice/),

> So what is the solution used by Google
>   Gmail?
>
> The solution is really simple,
>   straight forward and very portable!
>   What Gmail did is requesting an
>   endless html page that contains
>   streams of Javascript portions. Give
>   it a try, It’s very powerful. So, we
>   will have on the client side a js file
>   that processes the responses, and
>   another endless html that contains the
>   Javascript Streams.

The rest of the article goes into much more detail, including an exploration of alternatives as well as the specific one picked by GMail.

Comment: It is a good article. But, it still doesn't explain why GMail choose JSON as response in Firefox.

Comment: @Morgan, JSON's a nice way indeed to package data, especially though not exclusively for Javascript's use -- cfr http://ajaxian.com/archives/json-vs-xml-the-debate and (esp.) the many links therefrom. With chunked transfer-encoding, it works fine... at least in decently standard-compliant browsers;-).

Comment: Hi, tried waybackmachine for the article because the article is down. Can you deliver another link? Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the article is down" -- just visited http://ajaxian.com/archives/json-vs-xml-the-debate and it's right there.

Comment: I think @DOCASAREL is referring to the link in the Answer.